# Ordered lists and class thread-safety

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

I have a class which has:

- 2 fields holding time-ordered list (list1, list2).
- 3 read-only methods which iterate above lists to
  generate summary statistics.
- 1 mutating method, which looks for a match of given 'new-item' in list1. *If match is not found*, it adds 'new-item' to list1. *If match is found*, it removes the match from list1 and adds both match and 'new-item' to list2.

Lets assume that multiple concurrent invocation of all methods are possible. I need to achieve thread-safety while maximising performance.

**Approach1 (extremely slow)** - Declare field-types as `ArrayList` and use synchronise keyword on all methods.

**Approach2** - Declare field-type as `CopyOnWriteArrayList` and synchronise the mutating method.

**Questions**

1. Does Approach2 ensure thread-safety?
2. Are there better alternatives?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedCollection(java.util.Collection)

Comment: Are there multiple concurrent invocations of the mutating method going to happen?

Comment: Note that if you plan to use spliterator/stream/parallelStream/Iterator on synchronized collections, you must handle the synchronization yourself. It does not seem to be documented in the javadoc, but there is comments about it in the source code of the internal class.

Comment: `copyOnWriteArrayList` is also slow as it requires O(n) for every insertion

Comment: What kind of ordered collections do you have? Array lists? Sorted maps? What do you require from the collections? Is the mutating method inserting items always to the one and the same collection, or to two different ones?

Comment: yes, lets assume that multiple concurrent invocation of all methods are possible. Mutating method normallly inserts 'new item' into list1 but sometimes when it finds a match in list1 for 'new item', it removes that match and adds both match and 'new item' in list2. @ciamej

Comment: When you transfer an item, would it be allowed for some threads to observe a state when the item is present (for a short time) in both collections? or if the item would disappear (for a short time)?

Comment: What do you mean by "match" — is it simple equality check or something more complex? What kind of statistics is calculated by read-only methods. Is it possible to maintain the up-to date statistics with each update without full traversal of the lists?

Answer (score 2):

Do you need the random access offered by an ArrayList?  Can you instead use a thread-safe ordered collection like [ConcurrentSkipListSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html) (non-blocking) or [PriorityBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html) (blocking)?  Both have log(n) insertions.

Mutation methods in both cases are thread-safe.

**Edit:** Just note, you would still run into atomicity concerns.  If you need the add's to be done attomically then you would need more coarse locking.

Comment: I dont need random access of the list. You are right about atomic concerns. Because even after making both list individually threadsafe, in order to maintain the combined invariants on both list, further level of synchronisation is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Approach number 2 does not guarantee thread-safety.

The two operations on collections are not atomic: first you remove an item, then you add it to the other collection. Some thread might in the meantime execute a read-only method to find out that the item is missing in list 1, and is not yet added to the list 2. It depends on your application whether this is acceptable.

On the other hand, it is also possible that: a read-only method first iterates through list 1, and finds that it contains item x; in the meantime the updating method executes and transfers item x; the read-only method continues and iterates through list 2 in which it finds item x one more item. Again, it depends on your application whether this is acceptable.

Other solutions are possible, but that would require more details about what are you trying to achieve exactly.

One obvious way would be to modify approach number 1, and instead of using synchronized on every method, use a readers-writer lock. You would read-lock in every read-only method and write-lock in the mutating one.

You could also use two separate readers-writer locks. One for the first collection and one for the other. If your read-only methods iterate through both of the lists, they would have to read-acquire both of the locks up front, before doing anything. On the other hand the mutating method would have to first write-acquire the first lock, and if it wishes to transfer an item, then it should write-acquire the second lock.

You'd need to do some testing to see if it works nicely for you. Still there are definitely even better ways to handle it, but you'd need to provide more details.

Answer (score 1):

The time it takes to lock a method is less than a micro-second.  If a fraction of a micro-second matters, you might consider something more complex, both otherwise something simple is usually better.

Just using thread safe collection is not enough when you perform multiple operations, e.g. remove from one list and add to another is two operations, and any number of thread can get in between those operations.

Note: if you do lots of updates this can be slower.